# Is it possible to get the value of a DOM select element in IE6?

Tags: javascript, html-select, internet-explorer-6

So I'm having a cross-browser JavaScript issue.

I've got a `<select>` DOM element that has some descendent `<option>` element with `selected=true`.

In Firefox, I can just do `select_elt.value` to get the value of the selected option, but this seems not to work in IE6 (which I need to support).

I tried to iterate through the `select_elt.getElementsByTagName('option')` to find the selected `<option>`, which I could do, but `option_elt.value` still doesn't give me the value of that option.

So what is the appropriate way to get the value of an option or select element in IE6 (yes, I know I *should* switch to jQuery or some other cross-platform library, and I may yet, but now I'm curious about how this is done **at all** in IE6)?

Comment: could you post the whole code you use to get the value?
IE6 should support the option.value property.
Also, instead of interating through the options, have you tried using the selectedIndex property? as in select.options[select.selectedIndex] ?
Also, it isn't a multi-select, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most cross-browser compatible way (in my experience) to do that:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
alert(mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it [in jquery](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2.js):

```
(option_elt.attributes.value || {}).specified ? option_elt.value : option_elt.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select_elt.options[select_elt.options.selectedIndex].value
```